# GAMM4 models in R with either a continuous OR categorial variable in the smooth, and model comparison

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, model-selection, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

**To note**: I am fairly new to GAMMs. I have read many StackExchange questions/answers and general documentation on GAMMs, and consistently question the proper way to set up my models to answer my question.

**My research question**: Does disease status or temperature drive changes to timing in reproduction?

- Dependent variable(s): reproductive status (proportion of either pregnant/lactating/juveniles) gathered from 1985–2021
- Independent variables of average monthly temperature ; disease is coded as a factor with three levels ; day of year

**My idea was to set up 4 models**: one for each avg. monthly temperature (March, April, May) for each day of year and the final model with the disease status (WNS) for each day of year. I've provided two of the models below. I did not want a model with all variables as it does not make biological sense to do this.

**My thought process**: I want to then use AICc to compare those four models for each reproductive status to see whether temperature OR disease drives the proportion of individuals in each status. Thus I have REML = FALSE for Maximum Liklihood for AICc comparison.

Random notes on the models:
link = "cloglog" for many zeros
bs = "cr" as I am now having convergence issues (for large datasets) at least when I put April_temp or WNS outside the smooth.

```
>library(gamm4)

m1 <- gamm4(cbind(EPFU.F.PG, EPFU.ADF.TOT.JJ) ~ s(Day.of.year, by = April_temp, bs = "cr"),
            data = EPFU, 
            random = ~ (1|SITENAME), 
            REML = FALSE,
            family = binomial(link = "cloglog"))
```

**For the model above (m1)**:

- 1. Can a continuous variable be in the "by" statement? Temperature does vary by day of year.
- 2. If so, should this variable also be outside of the smooth? e.g. ~ April_temp + s(Day.of.year, by = April_temp, bs = "cr")

```
m2 <- gamm4(cbind(EPFU.F.PG, EPFU.ADF.TOT.JJ) ~ WNS + s(Day.of.year, by = WNS, bs = "cr"), 
            data = EPFU, 
            random = ~ (1|SITENAME), 
            REML = FALSE,
            family = binomial(link = "cloglog"))
```

**For the above model (m2)**:

- 3. As WNS is a factor with 3 levels (and varies by Day.of.year), I assume that WNS needs to both be within and outside the smooth based on what I've read. Is this correct?
- 4. How do I then interpret the output of the factor versus the smoothed factor when reporting? A good source for interpretation would be appreciated.

```
Formula:
cbind(EPFU.F.PG, EPFU.ADF.TOT.JJ) ~ WNS + s(Day.of.year, by = WNS,
    bs = “cr”)
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -2.5283     0.0953 -26.530   <2e-16 ***
WNS1         -0.1233     0.1316  -0.937   0.3487
WNS2         -0.2453     0.1149  -2.134   0.0328 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                      edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
s(Day.of.year):WNS0 3.587  3.587  113.2  <2e-16 ***
s(Day.of.year):WNS1 4.641  4.641  181.9  <2e-16 ***
s(Day.of.year):WNS2 3.634  3.634  360.6  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
R-sq.(adj) =  -0.418
glmer.ML = 1531.5  Scale est. = 1         n = 14209
```

**Overall**:

- 5. Can I compare these models (WNS versus all month temperature models) using AICc? Is there anything I should be cautious of when doing so?
- 6. Are there any recommended model checks given the above models? I've seen many potential options/examples, but not certain the best route to take.

Hopefully I've provided enough context.

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not equipped to answer all of these questions (I'm trying to figure out how to work with gamm4 models myself, and there appears to be a dearth of information on them).  For a general background on using splines, I've found the following youtube tutorial to be useful:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgw4cu8hrZM, but it doesn't get into the peculiarities of gamm4 and its output at all.  With that caveat, here are a few pointers that might help you (or others if you've already moved on)

1. I'm not sure why you would want a continuous variable in the "by" statement.  This is asking the model to create a separate smooth for each value of `April_temp`.  Is that really what you want?  (This, and other options, are explained in the video above).
2. If you really want to put `April_temp` as a by variable in the spline, it should also be listed in the model, probably as a factor?
3. If you want to estimate a different smooth for each value of WNS, then it needs to be included both inside and outside the smooth.  If you want the same smooth with a different intercept, it would only be listed outside the smooth.
4. Again, I found the video on youtube to be the most useful for interpreting splines in general.  For combining information from the `mer` and `gam` components of the output?  I'm still working on that!
5. The youtube tutorial does cover model checking, but not all of them will get created automatically when using gamm4.  That would be a good place to start though.

Hopefully this helps address some of the questions.  I've tended to move towards Bayesian models when I have random effects, non-linear responses, and splines to improve on my ability to check models, and perform hypothesis testing over time.